# Scroll to top button in my website is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

my blog is www.xperiblog.com
I had a scroll to top button which worked correctly. 
But recently I removed my post navigation script. Now the button is not working. here's the codes

Scroll to top button CSS

```
#back-to-top {
     text-align:center;
     background:#f97e76;
     color:#fff;
     overflow:hidden;
     width:60px;
     height:30px;
     display:block;
     margin:0 auto;
     border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
     border-top:3px solid #d26b64;
     cursor:pointer;
     background-image:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YQ-kX3Ifzb4/U6a5HhEhlLI/AAAAAAAADxI/wT_VI6RLrHM/s1600/totop.png);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position:center;
}
 #back-to-top a {
     color:#fff;
}
 #back-to-top a:hover {
     color:#f0f0f0;
}
```

Scroll to top button Script

```
<script>
$("#back-to-top").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
</script>
```

Script I removed

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var pageNaviConf = {
        perPage: 5,
        numPages: 5,
        firstText: "First",
        lastText: "Last",
        nextText: "Next",
        prevText: "Prev";
    }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    function pageNavi(o){var m=location.href,l=m.indexOf("/search/label/")!=-1,a=l?m.substr(m.indexOf("/search/label/")+14,m.length):"";a=a.indexOf("?")!=-1?a.substr(0,a.indexOf("?")):a;var g=l?"/search/label/"+a+"?updated-max=":"/search?updated-max=",k=o.feed.entry.length,e=Math.ceil(k/pageNaviConf.perPage);if(e<=1){return}var n=1,h=[""];l?h.push("/search/label/"+a+"?max-results="+pageNaviConf.perPage):h.push("/?max-results="+pageNaviConf.perPage);for(var d=2;d<=e;d++){var c=(d-1)*pageNaviConf.perPage-1,b=o.feed.entry[c].published.$t,f=b.substring(0,19)+b.substring(23,29);f=encodeURIComponent(f);if(m.indexOf(f)!=-1){n=d}h.push(g+f+"&max-results="+pageNaviConf.perPage)}pageNavi.show(h,n,e)}pageNavi.show=function(f,e,a){var d=Math.floor((pageNaviConf.numPages-1)/2),g=pageNaviConf.numPages-1-d,c=e-d;if(c<=0){c=1}endPage=e+g;if((endPage-c)<pageNaviConf.numPages){endPage=c+pageNaviConf.numPages-1}if(endPage>a){endPage=a;c=a-pageNaviConf.numPages+1}if(c<=0){c=1}var b='<span class="pages">Pages '+e+' of '+a+"</span> ";if(c>1){b+='<a href="'+f[1]+'">'+pageNaviConf.firstText+"</a>"}if(e>1){b+='<a href="'+f[e-1]+'">'+pageNaviConf.prevText+"</a>"}for(i=c;i<=endPage;++i){if(i==e){b+='<span class="current">'+i+"</span>"}else{b+='<a href="'+f[i]+'">'+i+"</a>"}}if(e<a){b+='<a href="'+f[e+1]+'">'+pageNaviConf.nextText+"</a>"}if(endPage<a){b+='<a href="'+f[a]+'">'+pageNaviConf.lastText+"</a>"}document.write(b)};(function(){var b=location.href;if(b.indexOf("?q=")!=-1||b.indexOf(".html")!=-1){return}var d=b.indexOf("/search/label/")+14;if(d!=13){var c=b.indexOf("?"),a=(c==-1)?b.substring(d):b.substring(d,c);document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/summary/-/'+a+'?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=99999"><\/script>')}else{document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=99999"><\/script>')}})();
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Anyone know whats going on here.

Comment: Well, if that's how your js/css looks in your editor, than that's your problem. If it was just a copy paste error, I suggest fixing the question so people can see your code as you see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can clean this code a bit, please see below:

html

```
<a href="#top" id="back-to-top" title="Back to top" class="show"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" style="font-size:22px;"></i></a>
```

css

```
#back-to-top {
font-size: 18px !important;
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999;
color: #e60000;
cursor: pointer;
bottom: 2em;
right: 2em;
text-decoration: none;
transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
opacity: 0;
}

#back-to-top.show {
opacity: 1;
}
```

js

```
if (jQuery('#back-to-top').length) {
var scrollTrigger = 100, // px
    backToTop = function () {
        var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > scrollTrigger) {
            jQuery('#back-to-top').addClass('show');
        } else {
            jQuery('#back-to-top').removeClass('show');
        }
    };
backToTop();
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function () {
    backToTop();
});
jQuery('#back-to-top').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   jQuery('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 700);
});
```